# Admob statistic empty, but advert showing

Tags: admob

I have AdMob adverts in my apps, every things works fine until last days

But now statistic show no shows adverts, but on application advert still showing.

Everything enabled

Notifications from Google i didn't receive.

[image]

Comment: should be fixed already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not the only one , hundreds of talking about it rite now

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk